# How can i create an array based on the user input?

Tags: arrays

I have the following code:

```
public class PlayerName {

     public void playerName(){

        int []playerNames = new int[playerNames[[n]];
        for(int n=0; n<=playerNames[n];n++){
            playerNames[n] = Helper.readInt("Enter no of players playing:  " );

        }
    }

}
```

I have been trying to initialise an array based on user input but they say I must create a local variable named `n`.

Comment: In the line int []playerNames = new int[playerNames[[n]]; you are using n without first declaring n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set it before could be something like this

```
public class PlayerName {
    public void playerName(){
    int x = Helper.readInt("Enter the dynamic For Value:  ");
    int []playerNames = new int[playerNames[[x]];
        for(int n=0; n<x;n++){
            playerNames[n] = Helper.readInt("Enter no of players playing:  " );

        }
    }
}
```